# CakePHP Current Paths not correct for cake bake

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

My currect paths prevent me from executing cake bake. I get the reply:
    What is the path to the project you want to bake?
    [c:\xampp\htdocs\musiclib\myapp] >
Hopefully the following details will reveal where I have gone wrong. In my XAMPP shell I get the following results when I execute the command, 'cake':

```
App : musiclib
Path: c:\xampp\htdocs\musiclib\  - this is the application I want to bake
Current Paths:
-app: musiclib
-working: c:\xampp\htdocs\musiclib
-root: c:\xampp\htdocs
-core: C:\xampp\htdocs\musiclib\lib
```

My environment variable path ends with ;C:\xampp\htdocs\musiclib\Cake\lib\Console;
My httpd-vhosts.conf contains

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/musiclib/app/webroot"
ServerName musiclib:80
ServerAlias localhost
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How should I prepare my paths to use cake bake?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running the bake shell from your project root and therefor Cake doesn't properly detect your app path. This can be seen by the `App : musiclib` bit in the output. That folder is not your app folder, obviously. Try one of these things:

1. Run it from your `app` folder. So `cd` into `app` and then:

   ..\lib\Cake\Console\cake bake
2. Use the `-app` flag to specify the path to your app folder. When inside your project root (`htdocs/musiclib`), run:

   lib\Cake\Console\cake bake -app app

Where the last `app` is the relative path to your app folder from where you are.

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed your first point and it worked! What a relief! Now I can start baking.